# Integrate Bootstrap theme with existing AngularJS project

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, frontend

I have an existing AngularJS project - a website with an average design, connected to a database and so forth. I want to integrate Bootstrap with this project, in order to achieve an appearance like the one found at this link: www.coreui.io I should install Bootstrap, but I don't figure out how to actually replace the styling (old styling with theme). There are .css files in my project which I want to remove and replace with the new ones found in the theme. 
What are the steps? I will provide more details if needed. Thank you!

Comment: Change the class names of your elements to that of Boostrap's.

Comment: And check out the examples to see how they work: https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/examples/

Answer (score 0):

You can copy "Dist" folder which contains all css and js files from theme and paste it in your existing project. after that change your index.html file.

Comment: There is no "dist" folder. The CoreUI project indeed has css, img, js etc. folders, but I don't know how to override my styling and add the theme to the existing project. I cannot simply copy these folders into my angularjs project.